# Temp Tables Calculating Fields

Tags: progress-4gl

I am joining two tables and outputting to a csv file. This has worked ok,
But I would like to create a calculated field (an integer field multiplied by a decimal field) and output that as one of the columns.
I am struggling at the moment to calculate the field and store it.

```
CREATE TEMP-TABLE tth2.                                                         
tth2:CREATE-LIKE(buf-woins-hndl).                                               
tth2:ADD-LIKE-FIELD("ttqtyhrs","work_order.est_ltime").                         
tth2:TEMP-TABLE-PREPARE("ordx2").                                               
bh2 = tth2:DEFAULT-BUFFER-HANDLE.                                               

FOR EACH wo_instr  NO-LOCK:                                                     
        bh2:BUFFER-CREATE.                                                      
        bh2:BUFFER-COPY(buf-woins-hndl).                                        
        ASSIGN  bh2:BUFFER-VALUE("ttqtyhrs") = bh2:BUFFER-VALUE ("craft_nbr") * 
bh2:BUFFER-VALUE("std_hrs").                                                    
END.
```

I am trying store the result of the calculation in temp table field ttqtyhrs
I get an error message

Invalid datatype for argument to method 'BUFFER-VALUE'. Expecting        'integer' (5442) 
when I try to compile.

I would be grateful for any pointers
Andy

Comment: It's a lot easier to help if you post code that is actually runnable (or at least runnable except for the actual error). There are two good ways of doing that: 1) Create an example with only temp-tables or 2) Create an example using the "sports"-database (the default Progress "tutorial" database).

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, was my first post here so the advice is very welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you want to something like this:

```
 ASSIGN  
    bh2:BUFFER-FIELD("ttqtyhrs"):BUFFER-VALUE() = bh2:BUFFER-FIELD("craft_nbr"):BUFFER-VALUE() * bh2:BUFFER-FIELD("std_hrs"):BUFFER-VALUE().
```

BUFFER-VALUE takes an integer representing the index if the field is an extent/array. You need to pinpoint the BUFFER-FIELD!

Comment: A trick to make this go faster is to store the buffer-field handles in variables before the loop so the AVM doesn't have to re-determine it on each iteration of the loop.

Comment: Hi This seemed to work many thanks for the quick replies bh2:BUFFER-FIELD("ttqtyhrs"):BUFFER-VALUE = bh2:BUFFER-FIELD("craft_nbr"):BUFFER-VALUE * bh2:BUFFER-FIELD("std_hrs"):BUFFER-VALUE.